# How to remove border from specific PrimeFaces p:panelGrid?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, facelets

I have difficulty in removing border from a specific PrimeFaces `<p:panelGrid>`.

```
<p:panelGrid styleClass="companyHeaderGrid">
    <p:row>
        <p:column>
            Some tags
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            Some tags
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

I have been able to remove border from the cells with:

```
.companyHeaderGrid td {
    border: none;
}
```

But

```
.companyHeaderGrid {
    border: none;
}
```

Does not work.

Comment: Balus' answer is outdated. See this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41585497/1599699

Comment: @Andrew I don’t think that this is a good answer.

Comment: @PaulWasilewski I think it is.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The border is been set on the generated `tr` and `td` elements, not on the `table`. So, this should do:

```css
.companyHeaderGrid.ui-panelgrid>*>tr,
.companyHeaderGrid.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
    border: none;
}
```

How I found it? Just check the generated HTML output and all CSS style rules in the webdeveloper toolset of Chrome (rightclick, *Inspect Element* or press F12). Firebug and IE9 have a similar toolset. As to the confusion, just keep in mind that JSF/Facelets ultimately generates HTML and that CSS only applies on the HTML markup, not on the JSF source code. So to apply/finetune CSS you need to look in the client (webbrowser) side instead.

[image]

#### See also:

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles/)
- [Remove border from all PrimeFaces p:panelGrid components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897664/remove-border-from-all-primefaces-ppanelgrid-components)

---

If you're still on PrimeFaces 4 or older, use below instead:

```css
.companyHeaderGrid.ui-panelgrid>*>tr,
.companyHeaderGrid.ui-panelgrid>*>tr>td {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: you can add the following to override primefaces styles:
.companyHeaderGrid tr, .companyHeaderGrid td {
    border: none !important;
}

Comment: @JohnB: the `!important` is unnecessary if you get your CSS loading order right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-those-classes-defined-in-primefaces-css/8774997#8774997 See also the answer of Andi here below and my comment on it. Do not use workarounds if there exist solutions. Use `!important` only as a true solution (i.e. when you need to override a hardcoded `style="..."` by a CSS selector declaration).

Comment: Thanks, work's for me, but to remove all borders i have to modify to
'
  .companyHeaderGrid.ui-panelgrid,
  .companyHeaderGrid.ui-panelgrid>*>tr,
  .companyHeaderGrid.ui-panelgrid>*>tr>td {
      border: none !important
  }
'

Answer (score 49):

I am using Primefaces 6.0 and in order to remove borders from my panel grid i use this style class "ui-noborder" as follow:

```
<p:panelGrid columns="3" styleClass="ui-noborder">
   <!--panel grid contents -->
</p:panelGrid>
```

It uses a css file named "components" in primefaces lib

Comment: I like this more than the solving answer as it sticks with the CSS framework.

Comment: Seems not to exist in PF's bootstrap theme?

Comment: What happens if the next PF version doesn’t provide the style class anymore or changes the class?

Comment: @Andrew i think you must be new. There are many css classes which have been introduced, changed and disappeared over the time ;)

Comment: Exactly. But because you're new you don't understand that this is the way you code in PF. There's no perfect solution, you have to suck it up and use non-ideal solutions all the time. This is excellent as far as PF is concerned.

Comment: See https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/panelgrid?id=blank-mode

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me:

```
.ui-panelgrid td, .ui-panelgrid tr
{
    border-style: none !important
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If BalusC answer doesn't work try this:

```
.companyHeaderGrid td {
     border-style: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: This is only applicable if your own CSS is not been loaded after PrimeFaces one, which is indeed a common starter's mistake. The `!important` declaration is then actually a workaround, not a solution. See for more detail also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-re-write-those-class-defined-in-primefaces-css/8774997#8774997

Answer (score 5):

If you find a line in between the columns then use the below code,

```
.panelNoBorder, .panelNoBorder tr, .panelNoBorder td{
border: hidden;
border-color: white;
}
```

I checked this with Primefaces 5.1

```
<h:head>
     <title>Login Page</title>    
     <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="common.css"/>
</h:head> 

<p:panelGrid id="loginPanel" columns="3" styleClass="panelNoBorder">
<p:outputLabel value="Username"/> <p:inputText id="loginTextUsername"/>
<p:outputLabel value="Password"/> <p:password id="loginPassword"/>
<p:commandButton id="loginButtonLogin" value="Login"/> <p:commandButton id="loginButtonClear" value="Clear"/>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: My Panelgrid is inside a DataTable & used for a selectOneRadio element with layout="custom". So this answer worked for me. Thanks a ton  :)

Answer (score 4):

Nowdays, Primefaces 5.x have a attribute in panelGrid named "columnClasses".

```
.no-border {
    border-style: hidden !important ; /* or none */
}
```

So, to a panelGrid with 2 columns, repeat two times the css class.

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="no-border, no-border">
```

To other elements, the ugly " !important " is not necessary, but to the border just with it work fine to me.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
<p:panelGrid styleClass="ui-noborder">
```

Comment: Please add explanation

Answer (score 0):

Just add those lines on your custom css mycss.css

```
table tbody .ui-widget-content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 0 solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #333333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by BalusC, the border is set by PrimeFaces on the generated `tr` and `td` elements, not on the `table`. However when trying with PrimeFaces version 5, it looks like there is a more specific match from the PrimeFaces CSS `.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell > solid` which still result in black borders being shown when appyling the style suggested.

Try using following style in order to overide the Primefaces one without using the `!important` declaration:

```
.companyHeaderGrid tr, .companyHeaderGrid td.ui-panelgrid-cell {
    border: none;
}
```

As mention make sure your CSS is [loaded after the PrimeFaces one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8774997/4201470).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want something more simple, you can just change:

```
<p:panelGrid >

</p:panelGrid>
```

to:

```
<h:panelGrid border="0">

</h:panelGrid>
```

That's worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

for me only the following code works

```
.noBorder tr {
border-width: 0 ;
}
.ui-panelgrid td{
    border-width: 0
}

<p:panelGrid id="userFormFields" columns="2" styleClass="noBorder" >
</p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the traditional as well as all the modern themes to have no border, apply the following;

```
<!--No Border on PanelGrid-->
    <h:outputStylesheet>
        .ui-panelgrid, .ui-panelgrid td, .ui-panelgrid tr, .ui-panelgrid tbody tr td
        {
            border: none !important;
            border-style: none !important;
            border-width: 0px !important;
        }
    </h:outputStylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I placed the panelgrid inside datatable, and hence my working solution is

```
.ui-datatable-scrollable-body .myStyleClass tbody td{border:none;}
```

for

```
<h:panelGrid  styleClass="myStyleClass" >...</h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

In primefaces, theme.css will have below code, just we need to specify styleClass as
'ui-panelgrid-blank'. So this will remove the border for panelGrid component.

```
.ui-panelgrid.ui-panelgrid-blank {
  border: 0 none;
  background: none;
}

<p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
</p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this too

```
.ui-panelgrid tr, .ui-panelgrid td {
border:0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use below style modification to remove border for Primefaces radio button

```
.ui-selectoneradio td, .ui-selectoneradio tr
{
    border-style: none !important
}
```