# Change selectOneMenu stylesheet (Primefaces)

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, styles

I want to change the background color of my selectOneMenu. When I try to set the style to `style="background-color:#f6f6f6"` there is no change at all.

I tried to wrap it  by a `div` and add a definition for it to the style.css but there has been no change so far.

Comment: Can you show more code? Maybe something is conflicting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `style` property is rather useless on `<p:selectOneMenu>`. Look at the generated HTML output by rightclick *View Source* or *Inspect Element*. It would be applied on the wrapper div, not on the concrete item, let alone the list. To style the selected item, you need to select the `.ui-selectonemenu-label` child of the menu via `styleClass` attribute . To style the list, you need to select the `.ui-selectonemenu-list` child of the panel (the dropdown) via `panelStyleClass` attribute.

So, all with all, this should do:

```
<p:selectOneMenu styleClass="menu" panelStyleClass="panel">
```

With

```css
.menu .ui-selectonemenu-label { 
    background: pink;
}
.panel .ui-selectonemenu-list { 
    background: pink;
}
```

Make sure that the CSS is initialized/loaded *after* PrimeFaces own styles. Best is to declare it in a `.css` file which is included by a `<h:outputStylesheet>` in the `<h:body>`.

#### See also:

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-re-write-those-class-defined-in-primefaces-css)
- [How to remove border from specific PrimeFaces p:panelGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421581/how-to-remove-border-from-primefaces-ppanelgrid/10421651#10421651)

Comment: Nice - only that `panelStyleClass` is [not documented](https://speakerdeck.com/player/057b8d7962d2466f9f24cd45f559b8da?slide=433#).

Answer (score 0):

You can style items easily if you use p:selectOneMenu. See guide for the style class names.

Maybe you can use jquery to add some styles.

```
menuWidget.items.eq(1).addClass('customclass')
```

Comment: this must be the same as `styleclass="backgroundclass"`, didn't work. I also set the background-color to !important

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to **override** default `primefaces.css` code for the `selectOneMenu`. To do so you have to lookup the style definition for particular element - in the file or i.e. with firebug.

For `selectOneMenu` it would be i.e `ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list` (depending on what do you want to style).

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/how-to-override-primefaces-css/) is a nice article about overriding default Primefaces styles.

**Note**: I would not personally use `!important` as described since it can be more harmful than useful later on.

Answer (score 0):

Similar Post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-re-write-those-class-defined-in-primefaces-css) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578494/how-to-override-stylesheets-of-primefaces).

You need to provide CSS for the element in more specific way as compared to its Primefaces specification.
Also as suggested by Fallup you shouldn't use `!important`, although it works but it has issues and it doesn't looks good either.