# How change the menubutton icon in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, icons

I would like to put a custom icon in a p:menuButton, is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yest it is possible. All you need to do is to **override** primefaces *css classes* generated for the `p:menuButton`.

Approach:

1. In the rendered web page you can right click on the generated `p:menuButton` and -> inspect element. There you can inspect all of the related *css classes*.
2. You can try to experiment with them (which I would advice, if you have time) for better understanding of *css selectors* and so on ...
3. The `.ui-menubutton .ui-state-default .ui-icon` are the classes that you need.

So now when you know which *css classes* are related to the icon you can override them :

Add `.ui-menubutton .ui-state-default .ui-icon` rule to your *stylesheet* (I assume you have one and it is sucesfully imported and working. If not check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14205456/1317692).)

*yourStyles.css* :

```
.ui-menubutton .ui-state-default .ui-icon {
    background: orange; /** insert your background image **/
}
```

This will override icons of all `p:menuButtons` used in your project. If you want to reduce it to some particular `p:menuButton` then add its ID to the *style* definition.

```
#menubID.ui-menubutton .ui-state-default .ui-icon {
        background: orange; /** insert your background image **/
    }
```

Comment: Now, just to complete solving my doubts, I would like to know if you have to remove the text of the button. When I don't pass value to the value attribute button it displays the text "ui-button". Thanks.

Comment: Oh! I really haven't thought of it! (I had removed the value attribute of the statement) <br/> Now, I declared the value passing a empty string and worked perfectly. Thank you @Fallup.