# Remove border from all PrimeFaces p:panelGrid components

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, border, panelgrid

I need to hide all borders of all panelgrids using primefaces. I have tried he following without effects:

```
table {
    border: none;
}

table tr, table td {
    border: none;
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to be **at least** as specific as the PrimeFaces default selector.

```css
.ui-panelgrid>*>tr,
.ui-panelgrid .ui-panelgrid-cell {
    border: none;
}
```

Do not use `!important` unless you need to override a hardcoded `style` on a HTML element.

#### See also:

- [How to remove border from specific PrimeFaces p:panelGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421581/how-to-remove-border-from-specific-primefaces-ppanelgrid)
- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-those-classes-defined-in-primefaces-css/8774997#8774997)

Comment: Excuse me, I delete my comment because !important fix the problem. I don't know what I need to do that in primefaces 5.1. Your answer is right

Comment: The `!important` flag is a workaround, not a solution. The right solution is to alter the CSS selector accordingly to fit the changes in PrimeFaces 5.1 default CSS. See also the first link in the answer for detail on that.

Comment: Yes I know. I learned it from you months ago. It is only a temporal solution

Comment: This remove the datatable cells borders too in primefaces 5.1. I need this fix only in panelGrid components

Comment: I am using PrimeFaces 5.2 and this did not work for me. I used codes from http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=42334 instead

Answer (score 1):

This solution affect only panelGrids but dataTables:

```
.ui-panelgrid > * > tr, .ui-panelgrid > * > tr > td.ui-panelgrid-cell {
    border: none;
}
```

Thanks to the answer published by  **Kukeltje** here: [Remove all border on all panelgrids not on datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437932/remove-all-border-on-all-panelgrids-not-on-datatables/31456192#31456192)

Comment: That comment was from Kukeltje.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your CSS is overwritten somewhere else.
You could try using the `!important` rule.

```
table, table tr, table td {
   border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Ok, you are right but I don't understand why it is happening if I am including my style.css file in the body

Comment: Is there an other stylesheet? Or inline style? It could also be that another rule in style.css is more specific and therefor applies before the above one.

Comment: No there isn't. I put my table style at the top of my css file and I don't have another css file in my project

Comment: `!important` is here not a solution. It's a workaround. Read on [CSS specificity, inheritance and cascading rules](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/). The `!important` should **only** be used when you'd like to override a style which is hardcoded in HTML element's `style` attribute. This is not the case here.

Answer (score -1):

Tested on primefaces 5.1

```
.ui-widget-content {
border: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This work in Primefaces 5

```
.ui-panelgrid-content {
    border: none;
}
```