# Hide border of <p:panelGrid> primefaces without affecting inner data table

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

How to hide the grid-line(border) of p:panelGrid without affecting the the border of  inner data table in primefaces 4.0

Currently using this CSS :

```
.ui-panelgrid td, .ui-panelgrid tr{
   border-style: none !important
}
```

which affects both data table and panel grid. But I want only panel grid lines to be hidden.

In my case data table is nested inside panel grid.

Thanks.

Comment: show us some code to understand the structure.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon change it to the following and try again:

    .ui-panelgrid tr, .ui-panelgrid td {
    border:none !important;
    }

Comment: @anas: No - if it's the last element within a css-class definition you don't have to. But it's best practice to do so.

Comment: Please visit: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421581/how-to-remove-border-from-primefaces-ppanelgrid][1] for a fix


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421581/how-to-remove-border-from-primefaces-ppanelgrid

Answer (score 5):

I know I'm late to party but I just came accross the same problem and fixed it by using a h:panelgrid (standard jsf-library) instead of the primefaces element. There you have the border attribute.

```
<h:panelGrid border= "0">
 [inner Table - not affected]
</h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 4):

As of version 5.3 (or earlier)

Blank Mode: 
To remove borders add `ui-noborder` style class to the component using `styleClass` attribute and to remove borders plus background color, apply `ui-panelgrid-blank` style.

Comment: Thanks. Works with Primefaces 5.3

Answer (score 3):

```
.ui-panelgrid tr, .ui-panelgrid td{
  border:none !important;
}

.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data tr,.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data-empty tr,.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data td,.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-data-empty td{
  border:1px solid !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your CSS file:

```
.ui-panelgrid > tr td, .ui-panelgrid > tr{
   border-style: none !important
 }
```